# Update Access table list all the number between two sets given

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an Access database where the user enters two set of numbers, for example `63` and `120`.

In another table I need to have all the numbers `>=63` and `<=120` listed.

How would I do this?

Comment: You can create a query that ask the user for those 2 numbers, and then show the results that fullfill those requirements

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but I need the query to show all list all the numbers between the users entered numbers. I don't not want a query that only selects a certain numbers.    For example, is a user enters 52 and 60  the query will show 52, 53,,,,59,60 for that user.

Comment: Without a data example, the input and the expected output, your question is unclear about what you are asking. Anyways, as I Said, you can do it **exactly** as I said. It's like a filter. Filter to values between 63 and 120

Comment: I'd have 2 text boxes on a form, one for each number and a command button. Under the command button, I'd create a VBA For loop that inserts each number into the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a table called `numbers` with a single field called `id` of **Long Integer** data type:

  [image]
- Populate this table with the integers **0** through **9**:

  [image]
- You can then use a query such as the following which implements a [cross join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join) (also known as a [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)) to yield the numbers 1-1000:

  ```
  select 100*n100.id+10*n10.id+n1.id+1 as n from numbers n1, numbers n10, numbers n100
  ```

  If your quantity is not likely to exceed 100, this may become:

  ```
  select 10*n10.id+n1.id+1 as n from numbers n1, numbers n10
  ```

  If your quantity is likely to exceed 1000, the following will yield 10000 records:

  ```
  select 1000*n1000.id+100*n100.id+10*n10.id+n1.id+1 as n 
  from numbers n1, numbers n10, numbers n100, numbers n1000
  ```

  (Expand/contract the pattern for the order of magnitude suitable for your data)
- The final step is to apply appropriate selection criteria to select the range of numbers required:

  ```
  select t.n from
  (select 100*n100.id+10*n10.id+n1.id+1 as n from numbers n1, numbers n10, numbers n100) t
  where t.n >= val([Enter lower bound]) and t.n <= val([Enter upper bound])
  ```